# É adequado usar camadas em uma aplicação usando microsserviços?

Tags: aplicação-web, arquitetura-de-software, microsserviços

Estruturar uma aplicação web em camadas é utilizado somente em aplicações monolíticas ou também em microsserviços?

- Presentation layer
- Application layer
- Business logic layer
- Data access layer

Comment: Também em micro-serviços.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado cada serviço implementa as quatro camadas ou cada serviço é uma  camada?

Comment: Não é assim que se pensa em micro-serviço. Em uma das arquiteturas de micro-serviços que eu conheço, casa serviço é responsável por uma lógica/um recurso. Assim, eu posso ter um serviço de clientes mais voltado à camada de acesso, e um serviço de pedidos que, por sua vez, está mais na camada de negócios. Particularmente **eu** não conheço a camada de aplicação. E a camada de apresentação é outra conversa, normalmente monolítica. Mas tem pelo menos 1 framework JS que permite micro-arquiteturar a apresentação.

Comment: Leitura interessante (no SE.SE): https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361272/does-layered-architecture-still-to-be-implemented-inside-all-other-architecture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sou especialista em microsserviços, no máximo gosto de indicar como microsserviços não são úteis na imensa maioria dos casos, e ele só acrescenta complexidade sem dar ganhos reais, exceto nos casos de extrema complexidade do domínio, necessidade de escala absurdamente alta, ou onde o microsserviço encaixa naturalmente.

Mas entendo que microsserviços seja uma técnica travestida de arquitetura para gerenciar complexidade. Se ela realmente faz isso, porque usar outra técnica para gerenciar complexidade, que é o caso da separação em camadas? Não que não possa, mas me parece que seja um caso da pessoa nem entender porque está adotado essas técnicas.

Se realmente o serviço for micro ele é tão simples que a separação em camadas se torna menos ou totalmente desnecessária. A adoção do microsserviço deveria vir acompanhada de uma nova forma de programar, pensando que você tem pequenos *jobs*, como era no passado em *mainframes* e os códigos eram muito pequenos. Se isso não acontece, provavelmente não está fazendo exatamente microsserviço. O mesmo vale para orientação a objeto que foi criado para gerenciar grandes aplicações e não pequenas.

Note que em parte a camada já pode ser um micro ou pelo menos um mediosserviço. A apresentação em si costuma ser no cliente e não no servidor, então ele já é um serviço, de uma certa forma (claro que depende da forma como foi montada).

Eu já costumo dizer que o uso de MVC na maioria dos casos é um canhão pra matar passarinho. Em muitos casos é a adoção de camadas só para duplicar esforços sem um ganho claro. Mas faz sentido em algo complexo.

A maioria das tecnologias e metodologias novas são criadas muito informalmente. Não existe um documento canônico que diga o que pode ou não fazer em microsserviços. Eu vejo muitas pessoas usando camadas igual fazem no monolítico, eu vejo mais ainda as pessoas adotando microsserviços sem precisar, sem entender os problemas que eles trazem, sem se dar conta que na maioria dos casos acabará criando uma plataforma de algo que já estava pronto se adotasse o monólito, ou seja, tentando "simplificar" complica imensamente o que estava fazendo.

E eu já vi pessoas duplicando esforços aos montes para conseguir fazer microsserviços. Aí eu vi pelo menos um caso onde provavelmente dariam conta do problema com menos de 100 programadores e foram para mais de 1000 depois de adotar o microsserviço. Mas eles acham que assim estão fazendo certo, e principalmente estão na moda.

E quando eu falo de escala estou falando de muita escala, lembre-se que você está agora em um dos 50 sites mais acessados do mundo e eles rechaçam o microsserviço, e justamente por isso são tão bons. Só para dar uma comparação, o exemplo citado no parágrafo anterior nem chega perto desse tráfego todo, mas possuem milhares de servidores, enquanto este site aqui pode rodar em apenas um servidor se quiser (não o faz para dar mais confiabilidade, principalmente em momentos de ataque DDOS).

Microsserviços são montados baseando-se em funcionalidades e não dizem nada sobre camadas, você as pode usar se quiser. Algumas pessoas dizem que cada camada deve ser um serviço, alguns chamam isso de nanosserviço.

Então deve se perguntar porque vai adotar microsserviço. E porque vai adotar camada. Se não puder justificar essas escolhas e demonstrar claramente que haverá vantagens, simplesmente não as adote. Não faça porque está todo mundo fazendo.

[image: Tomada com gambiarras para encaixar o plugue de energia em vez de colocar o pino diretamente]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Em um caso que não seja tão complexo o que poderia ser utilizado no lugar do MVC?

Comment: Em C# a Microsoft recomenda https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio.

Comment: Conhece algum para Java?

Comment: Não, Java tende a fazer as cosias sempre do jeito mais complicado :D Mas sempre dá para fazer de forma mais simples sem usar esses *framewoks* malucos. Na verdade o problema não é achar algo pronto que seja mais simples, é entender o problema e saber qual é a solução. Trocar uma receita de bolo por outra pode até ajudar, mas ainda não é a solução final. Curiosamente os programadores de PHP faziam coisas simples muito bem, aí um dia inventaram que tava simples demais e começaram complicar :D Pega o jeito antigo de fazer PHP, este é o caminho pra maioria dos casos.

Comment: Por isso que PHP é denominada a linguagem de sobrinho, né? Por conta da sua simplicidade :)

Comment: Curiosamente piorou muito quando começaram fazer mais complicado. Na verdade é tão "de sobrinho" que as pessoas nem sabem mais que o jeito que é feito nela hoje não é mais simples. O jeito simples praticamente morreu (claro, ainda dá para fazer, mas você nem acham exemplos, você tem que descobrir, tem que começar aprender programar antes de aprender a linguagem para chegar nesse ponto. Hoje a maioria só aprende a linguagem, só receita de bolo, não entendem o que é programar de verdade.